# nls function in R within functions and lists

Tags: r, list, function, environment, nls

I am working with a package written in R-to fit experimental data to specific models
and I want to write my own model and use same package(authors claim it is possible).

So I am digging the source files to find where they define the model functions. I am stuck
by the way they use `nls`. I understood how `nls` work for the case below

```
x <- -(1:100)/10
y <- 100 + 10 * exp(x / 2) + rnorm(x)/2
nlmod <- nls(y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x),start=list(Const=5,A=5,B=7))
```

create a data set and write the model next to it-easy.

However they use `nls` as shown below:

```
>  nls(~rescomp(theta = t, d = d, currModel = currModel), 
>     data = list(d = vector(), currModel = currModel))
```

when I run

```
>  ~rescomp(theta = t, d = d, currModel = currModel)
```

to see a formula as in the example above (Const + A * exp(B * x)). I get this

```
~rescomp(theta = t, d = d, currModel = currModel) 

environment: 0x000000000a7f7530
```

I want to learn how I can see the resultant formula and how `nls`
work while data is set to list\environment. Any suggestions?

Here is the content of `rescomp`

```
  function (theta = vector(), d = vector(), currModel = currModel, 
    currTheta = vector()) 
{
    if (length(currTheta) == 0) 
        currTheta <- getThetaCl(theta, currModel)
    groups <- currModel@groups
    m <- currModel@modellist
    resid <- clpindepX <- list()
    nexp <- length(m)
    for (i in 1:nexp) {
        clpindepX[[i]] <- if (!m[[i]]@clpdep || m[[i]]@getX) 
            getClpindepX(model = m[[i]], theta = currTheta[[i]], 
                multimodel = currModel, returnX = FALSE, rawtheta = theta, 
                dind = 0)
        else matrix()
    }
    for (i in 1:length(groups)) {
        resid[[i]] <- residPart(model = m[[1]], group = groups[[i]], 
            multimodel = currModel, thetalist = currTheta, clpindepX = clpindepX, 
            finished = currModel@finished, returnX = FALSE, rawtheta = theta)
        if (currModel@finished) {
            currModel <- fillResult(group = groups[[i]], multimodel = currModel, 
                thetalist = currTheta, clpindepX = clpindepX, 
                rlist = resid[[i]], rawtheta = theta)
        }
    }
    if (currModel@finished) {
        currModel@fit@nlsres$onls$nclp <- currModel@nclp
        if (currModel@optlist[[1]]@sumnls) {
            if (class(currModel@fit@nlsres$onls) == "nls") 
                class(currModel@fit@nlsres$onls) <- "timp.nls"
            else if (class(currModel@fit@nlsres$onls) == "nls.lm") 
                class(currModel@fit@nlsres$onls) <- "timp.nls.lm"
            else class(currModel@fit@nlsres$onls) <- "timp.optim"
            currModel@fit@nlsres$sumonls <- summary(currModel@fit@nlsres$onls, 
                currModel = currModel, currTheta = currTheta)
        }
        if (currModel@stderrclp) {
            for (i in 1:length(groups)) {
                currModel <- getStdErrClp(group = groups[[i]], 
                  multimodel = currModel, thetalist = currTheta, 
                  clpindepX = clpindepX, rlist = resid[[i]], 
                  rawtheta = theta) 
       }
        if (currModel@stderrclp) {
            for (i in 1:length(groups)) {
                currModel <- getStdErrClp(group = groups[[i]], 
                  multimodel = currModel, thetalist = currTheta, 
                  clpindepX = clpindepX, rlist = resid[[i]], 
                  rawtheta = theta)
            }
        }
    }
    if (currModel@finished && currModel@trilinear) {
        trires <- triResolve(currModel, currTheta)
        currModel <- trires$currModel
        currTheta <- trires$currTheta
    }
    if (currModel@finished && m[[1]]@mod_type == "kin") {
        if (m[[1]]@fullk) {
            for (i in 1:nexp) {
                nocolsums <- length(m[[1]]@lightregimespec) > 
                  0
                eig <- fullKF(currTheta[[i]]@kinpar, currTheta[[i]]@kinscal, 
                  m[[1]]@kmat, currTheta[[i]]@jvec, m[[1]]@fixedkmat, 
                  m[[1]]@kinscalspecial, m[[1]]@kinscalspecialspec, 
                  nocolsums)
                currTheta[[i]]@eigenvaluesK <- eig$values
            }
        }
    }
    if (currModel@finished) {
        return(list(currModel = currModel, currTheta = currTheta))
    }
    if (currModel@algorithm == "optim") 
        retval <- sum(unlist(resid))
    else retval <- unlist(resid)
    retval
}
```

Comment: Putting `rm(list=ls())` in your sample code is not a great idea.

Comment: try typing just `rescomp`

Comment: Senor O, I forgot to delete that line.

Comment: @Ben Bolker,I already look into `rescomp` to find the formula but couldn't get it. `rescomp` turns the the content of function.rescomp is too long to write here

Comment: `nls` simply evaluates `rescomp` with different starting variables to minimize error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula. `nls` is repeatedly passing a call to a function that is pulling in 'currModel' and parameters (probably theta and d) which are to be minimized based on the scalar that is returned from the `rescomp` function. Your complaint that the results of typing "rescomp" are "too long to write here" is simply an indication that a) you don't understand that you should be editing your question rather than writing that output in the comments, and b) that your expectations of what is happening are too narrow.

To illustrate writing your first nls problem as a functional form:

```
myfunc <- function(Const,A,B,y=y,x=x) { abs(y - ( Const + A * exp(B * x)))}
```

So you will be minimizing the absolute deviation of y from predicted:

```
nlmod <- nls( ~myfunc(Const,A,B,y=y,x=x) ,start=list(Const=5,A=5,B=7))
nlmod  # same results
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is really helpful.I also add the `rescomp` function above

Comment: If you want to see the formula that was driving the construction of the model then I would suggest you cannot find it in `rescomp` but rather by dissecting the `currModel`-object. My first suggestion would be to try `currModel$call`   ... If that is unsuccessful then report the results of `names(currModel)` and `class(currModel)`.